# How to set proxy for XML package in R

Tags: r

How to setup proxy for XML package?

The Rcurl package is working fine if I set:

```
options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy = "111.22.33.44.333", proxyport = 0000))
```

But id doesn't work for XML package functions.

If I set the explorer setup still nothing:

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
```

I have also added the `setInternet2(TRUE)` to .Rprofile but still is failing to take on the proxy. So how to assure the proxy is set globally or rather how to make it work for XML package function such as `readHTMLTable` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `RCurl` is working
try to download the HTML-Page via `getURL` and then parse it with `readHTMLTable`:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
url <- "yourURL.com"
doc_raw <- getURL(url)
tab <- readHTMLTable(doc_raw)
```

Comment: Actually, this solved my issue but will wait before accepting to see if someone else have something else to say. Thanks.

Comment: same here. Solved the issue for this specific caseby forcing to download using libcurl, even though it doesn't seem to be a general solution.